# Unknown mediator referenced by configuration element

Tags: wso2

I got this error after adding an email connector to my sequence.
I'm following this tutorial: https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/use-cases/tutorials/using-the-gmail-connector/

```
[2023-11-10 10:52:27,928] ERROR {MediatorFactoryFinder} - Unknown mediator referenced by configuration element : {http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse}email
[2023-11-10 10:52:27,928] ERROR {SequenceDeployer} - Sequence Deployment from the file : C:\IntegrationStudio\runtime\microesb\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1699609947789TestCompositeApplication_1.0.0.car\PaymentRequestProcessingSequence_1.0.0\PaymentRequestProcessingSequence-1.0.0.xml : Failed. org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Unknown mediator referenced by configuration element : {http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse}email
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.MediatorFactoryFinder.getMediator(MediatorFactoryFinder.java:246)
```

I have tried to:

- Rerunning the tutorial from the beginning
- Checked that all the necessary dependencies are loaded in SampleServicesCompositeExporter pom.xml
  NOTE: the error appears in the moment that I run the application using Export Artifacts and run command.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Connector Exporter project and add the connector so it will be deployed with the carbon application. Take a look at [this](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.0.0/micro-integrator/develop/creating-artifacts/adding-connectors/#packaging-connectors) document.